# HTML file linked by submit button to a PHP file, but when clicked 'Object Not Found'

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, form-submit

I am trying to link a HTML file that a user can input data into to a PHP file that will collect the inputted data

this is the HTML file called 'AddATeacher.html'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

      <h3>Input the information below... </h3>

  <form action="/action_page.php">
      First name:<input type="text" name="firstname"> (up to 40 Characters)
          <br>
      Last name:<input type="text" name="lastname"> (up to 40 Characters)
          <br>
      ID code:<input type="text" name="ID code">  (3 Characters)
          <br>
      Full Time?
      <input type="radio" name="Time" value="Full Time" checked><br>
      Part Time?
      <input type="radio" name="Time" value="Part Time"><br>
      Hours:<input type="text" name="Hours" > (input weekly hours, if full time then 23.5)
          <br>
      Room Preferenc:<input type="text" name="Room Preferenc" >
          <br>

    <a href="getAddATeacher"><input type="submit" value="Submit" ></a>




  </form>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is the PHP file I am trying to link it to called 'getAddATeacher.php'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["firstname"]; ?><br>


</body>
</html>
```

both files are stored in the same place, if that makes any difference?

Comment: `getAddATeacher` and `getAddATeacher.php` are **different URLs**

Comment: And `form action="/action_page.php"` .. is neither?

Comment: `<a href="getAddATeacher"><input type="submit" value="Submit" ></a>` — This is forbidden in HTML. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu). Link somewhere or submit a form. You can't do both.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have "action_page.php" as action of your form. So if you submit your form via submit button, it will be sent to "action_page.php" file. If you want to process your data in "getAddATeacher.php", you should change it in form action.

Btw. submit button of form can't be in link!

Comment: I have changed the code so the first line is;<form action="getAddATeacher">

Comment: and submit one to be <input type="submit">, but it still does not go to the other page, instead it says 'object not found

Comment: @pip because you need to add file extension, action should be "getAddATeacher.php".

Comment: Thankyou very much